# eclipse is showing error on render() in play2

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework-2.0

i am new on Play Framework and i am trying to develop sample java application

i have created new html page test.html

in controllers it is working if we simply return result in the form of string i.e. return           ok("hello world") but it simply format all the styling/text and just shows "hello world" on the UI.

```
 public static Result test() {
        return ok("hello world");
        }
```

// working fine

but it gives errors when i try this

```
public static Result test(){
        return ok(test.render());
        }
```

// giving error

it gives following errors

[error] /opt/ahsen/play-2.2.3/testapp/app/controllers/Application.java:15: render(java.lang.String,play.api.templates.Html) in views.html.test cannot be applied to ()

[error]         return ok(test.render());

[error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code

here is my test.html file

```
    @(title: String)(content: Html)

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
    <title>@title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
    <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> 
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test.html template requires two parameters

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)
```

So you need to pass them to the template in your controller

```
public static Result test(){ 
  String title = "test title";
  Html content = // create content
  return ok(test.render(title, content));
}
```

**Better solution**

Test.html looks rather as a more general layout template. I would create a separate file for generating content instead passing it directly from a controller.

content.html

```
@(title: String)

@test(title){
  <span>this is the content</span>
}
```

And in the controller it would look like this.

```
public static Result test(){ 
  String title = "test title";
  return ok(content.render(title));
}
```